# C# 4.0 MemoryCache - how to evict dependent cache entries when changes are made to their dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, caching, c#-4.0, memorycache

I am attempting to evict entries from a MemoryCache when changes are made to other entries on which they are dependent. This is being set up by creating cache entry change monitors for the dependencies on the dependent keys:

```
public bool AddToCache(string key, object dataItem, 
    DateTimeOffset absoluteExpiration, IEnumerable<string> dependencyKeys)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key) && dataItem != null)
    {
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy {
            AbsoluteExpiration = absoluteExpiration
        };

        if (masterKeys != null && masterKeys.Any())
        {
            policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(
                this.provider.Cache.
                    CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(dependencyKeys));

            foreach (ChangeMonitor monitor in policy.ChangeMonitors)
            {
                monitor.NotifyOnChanged(this.OnDependencyChanged);
            }
        }

        result = this.provider.Cache.Add(key, dataItem, policy);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The `OnChangedCallBack` method is this:

```
private void OnDependencyChanged(object state)
{
    // what do I do here as "state" is always null?
}
```

The items are added to the cache as intended, and the `OnDependencyChanged` method is called as expected when a change is made to a monitored key, however the "state" instance that is passed to it is always null which means that I know nothing about the cache key whose dependency has changed and can therefore not perform the planned eviction.

Have I missed something here, am I going about this all the wrong way?

Comment: Hi Jibberish, you marked the right answer follwoing, but I still cant understand why the answer is right, I even cant found where is OnChangedCacheEntry... I am faced the same problem, state always null, could you help explain a little more? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delegate that is used as a parameter in `OnChangedCacheEntry` is:

```
public delegate void OnChangedCallback(object state);
```

So you have to call it like this:

```
monitor.NotifyOnChanged(delegate {
       OnChangedCacheEntry(OnDependencyChanged(dependencyKeys)); });
```

And then you will have access to the dependency keys in OnDependencyChanged

```
private void OnDependencyChanged(object state)
{
    IEnumerable<string> dependencyKeys = (IEnumerable<string>) state;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old thread, but here's what I have and it seems to work.

```
...

if (dependencies != null)
{
    var monitor = MemoryCache.Default.CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(dependencies);
    monitor.NotifyOnChanged(delegate { OnChangedCallback(dependencies); });
    policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(monitor);
}

...

private static void OnChangedCallback(object state)
{
    var keys = (IEnumerable<string>) state;
    if (keys != null)
        Logger.InfoFormat("callback - {0}", string.Join("|", keys.ToArray()));
    else
        Logger.InfoFormat("callback - null");
}
```

The **dependencies** parameter in OnChangedCallback(**dependencies**) is what's missing from original post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you want to do is evict dependent entries, as OP stated, you don't need to worry about NotifyOnChanged. This is all you need:

```
public bool AddToCache(string key, object dataItem,
    DateTimeOffset absoluteExpiration, IEnumerable<string> dependencyKeys)
{
    CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    policy.AbsoluteExpiration = absoluteExpiration;

    ChangeMonitor monitor = MemoryCache.Default.CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(dependencyKeys);
    policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(monitor);

    return MemoryCache.Default.Add(key, dataItem, policy);
}
```